# Eclipse(CDT). Build+Terminate Current debug + Run after load on debug button is possible?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to give any kind of directives/commands so that when I press "Debug" button in Eclipse IDE, it would terminate all active debug sessions, build changes and after program is loaded - run application without need for me to make any additional clicks/inputs? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is _Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Launching: Terminate and Relaunch while launching_ what you're looking for?

Comment: Great!Two clicks less now! Is there any way that I don't need to press "Resume(F8)" afterwards?

Comment: _Resume_ from a breakpoint or watchpoint? If yes, what is the purpose of that breakpoint or watchpoint?

Comment: When I enter debug program is on break at main(). I mean, is there anyway to skip this so program starts running immideatly(and later in code might find another breakpoint to stop).

Comment: I think the breakpoint at `main()` is not necessary. But I don't know for sure. I am a Java developer and not a C/C++ expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @howlger said "Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Launching: Terminate and Relaunch while launching" for part 1.

To not have to press F8/resume, don't insert the breakpoint at main in the first place by disabling it in the Launch Configuration. From Run Menu -> Debug Configurations... -> Choose your launch -> Debug Tab, un check Stop on startup at.

[image]

You can change the default so newly created configurations have Stop on startup unchecked by going to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB.

[image]